# HTML element ids and backbone.js's scoped instance of $

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I've inherited a moderately complex codebase which makes heavy use of jQuery , backbone.js , and ejs templates.  Many of the templates in this codebase have HTML structured more or less like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <span id="baz"></span>
</div>
```

.  The view code backing these templates contains lots of functions like this:

```
function doSomeStuff() {
  this.$("#foo").hide();
}
```

.

When more than one of these views are present in the DOM, like if I'm rendering a Backbone collection, it will result in the DOM containing multiple elements with the same id.  [According to the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) that causes `document.getElementById()` to exhibit undefined behavior, and I'm pretty sure jQuery uses that function under the hood.  But the view code does seem to work correctly as currently written.

I noticed that this code is using the [scoped instance of jQuery provided to it by Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar).  My question is, am I able to rely on this scoped instance to always only select the proper elements?  Or am I just getting lucky here, and I really ought to re-write a lot of this code to do the Right Thing and use classes instead of ids?

Comment: `this.$(x)` is the same as `this.$el.find(x)`. I'm not sure what the internal implementation of jQuery's `find` is. I'd strongly recommend again depending on the current behavior though, duplicate `id`s is invalid HTML so everything is broken. I think `class="foo"` and `this.$('.foo')` would serve you better, I tend to avoid `id` attributes except in very narrow circumstances when I'm absolutely certain that duplicates will never be an issue.

Comment: Yeah there is rarely a good reason to use an id, and there should never be more than one on the page. Don't rely on the browser working around that bad practice.. use classes instead!

Answer (score 0):

In the world of web development, there are two sets of rules: the rules defined by the W3C (ie. the specifications), and the rules defined by the browsers (ie. what Google/Microsoft/Mozilla want).  For many years now `id` attributes have been a noticeable difference between those two rule sets: the W3C says that `id` attributes must be unique, but browsers couldn't care less.

This means that Backbone, jQuery, or any other tool (that isn't a W3C validator) won't care about multiple cases of the same `id` attribute.  This means that Backbone/jQuery won't go out of their way to help you, but it also means they aren't the source of your problem.

Personally, my recommendation would be this: don't worry about multiple idential `id` attributes because they won't hurt anything.  Browsers will cheerfully treat them like classes and all styles/jQuery selectors/etc. will continue to work.

Instead, focus on taming other aspects of your newly inherited complex codebase, aspects that can't be so easily ignored.  Then, once you've dealt with everything meaningful, you can come back and changes any `id` that is repeated in to a `class` attribute.  Both before and after you do that, Backbone, `this.$`, and jQuery in general, should all work without issue.